# Binary computation using Regex in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, binary

I am having trouble figuring these questions out. 
I want to use regex in JS to do this.

1.All binary strings of odd length containing alternating 0's and 1's.

2.All binary strings over 0 and 1 representing numbers greater than 5 when interpreted as binary numbers.

3.All binary strings over 0 and 1 representing numbers which are evenly divisible by 4 when interpreted as binary numbers.

4.All binary strings of length less than or equal to 5 containing only 0's and 1's where the number of 0's is equal to the number of 1's.

Any help is greatful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that RegExps aren't the best solutions to your problems, but here they are:

1. `\b(1(01)*|0(10)*)\b` [try in regexr](https://regexr.com/3vvvd)
2. `\b([01]*11[01]|0*1+[01]*[01]{3})\b` [try in regex](https://regexr.com/3vvvv)
3. `\b[01]*00\b` [try in regexr](https://regexr.com/3vvvs)
4. `\b((01|10){1,2}|0011|1100)\b` [try in regexr](https://regexr.com/3vvv7)

Answer (score 0):

I split this into 4 Regexes to easier understand:

1.

```
^(?:(?:10)+1|(?:01)+0)+$
```

This matches one or more of '`01`' or '`10`', followed by the opposite char, repeated one or more times.

2.

```
[01]{4,}$
```

This simply checks that the number ends with 4 binary digits.

3.

```
[01]*0{2,}$
```

This makes sure the number ends with 2 zeros.

4.

```
^(01|10|0011|0101|0110|1001|1010|1100)$
```

This simply `OR`'s the different possibilities. Since there has to be equal zeros and '1' there can only be 2 or 4 digits in the number.

If you need it all in one regex you can propably `OR` them all together.